# gunicorn worker not able to start, causing 502 Bad Gateway errors

Tags: networking, server

I am running a django app with nginx  1.14.0 and gunicorn, my virtual machine is Ubuntu 18.04.5.

Since this morning, trying to access my website, every page shows up with a 502 bad gateway error. Already yesterday, it was showing that page from time to time and a reload of the page would do the trick.

Upon login, I get the following message:

```
System information disabled due to load higher than 1.0
```

and then when I do `landscape-sysinfo`

```
System load:  9.05              Processes:           120
  Usage of /:   80.6% of 7.69GB   Users logged in:     1
  Memory usage: 34%               IP address for eth0: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  Swap usage:   0%
```

and here is the error that I get when trying to access any page of the site:

```
2020/11/06 11:18:40 [error] 981#981: *33 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream,
```

and in gunicorn:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in run
    self.sleep()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 357, in sleep
    ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
    self.reap_workers()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 228, in run
    super().run()
 File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
    self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
    self.stop()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
    time.sleep(0.1)
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
    self.reap_workers()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

I am new to nginx therefore I am not too sure on how to interpret this information as well as act upon. Advices are highly welcomed before I mess something up!

cheers!

UPDATE: running gunicorn manually with  `--debug-log debug` , I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 162, in init_process
    super().init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'inventory4'
```

Inventory4 is my django directory with the settings.py and wsgi.py

this is super strange because I have not made any modification to my project configuration.

here is what it looks like in django: settings.py:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'inventory4.wsgi.application'
```

and wsgi.py

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'inventory4.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and here is what i have configured in /etc/supervisor/conf.d/gunicorn.conf:

```
directory=/home/ubuntu/exostocksaas
command=/home/ubuntu/exo/bin/gunicorn  --config /home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/config.py --log-level debug --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/exostocksaas/app.sock inventory4.wsgi:application

autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.out.log


[group:guni]
programs:gunicorn
```

I have no clue what could have caused the bug to occur and how to solve it

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.5 and nginx 1.14.0, sorry for forgetting mentioning them

Comment: Do you know where the response comes from, i.e. nginx or gunicorn?

Comment: it comes from nginx, here is the error:```2020/11/06 11:18:40 [error] 981#981: *33 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream```

Comment: then it's obviously not a problem with nginx. Try to find out why the gunicorn worker fails to boot.

Comment: I agree, do you have a clue where to look at?